# Reclassify with a range with OR statements ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, reclassify

I need to Reclassify a raster. I have the following:

50-80% OR 10-15% that I want to assign the same value e.g 1 , how do I do this when there is a OR statement? Currently I can only set <=80 , only one value.

Comment: What ArcGIS Pro tool are you using?

Comment: Reclassify under Spatial Analyst Tool  (It is for a suitability analysis)

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the tool dialogue?